Integral of $x^2$ with respect to a probability distribution inequality with characteristic function
Let $X \colon \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ be a random variable with characteristic function $\phi(t) = \mathbb{E}[\exp(itX)]$. I have an exercise that asks me to show that for any $u > 0$,
\begin{equation}
\int_{[-\frac{1}{u},\frac{1}{u}]} x^2 \mathbb{P}_{X}(dx) \leq \frac{24}{11u^2}(1- \mathrm{Re}\: \phi(u)).
\end{equation}
A hint says to use the fact that $1 - \cos(x) \geq 0$ and that for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $1 - \cos(x) \geq \frac{1}{2} x^2 - \frac{1}{4} x^4$.
I'm having trouble showing this inequality. This is as far as I got:
\begin{align}
\int_{[-\frac{1}{u},\frac{1}{u}]} x^2 \mathbb{P}_{X}(dx) & = \frac{1}{u^2}\int_{[-\frac{1}{u},\frac{1}{u}]}(u x)^2 \mathbb{P}_{X}(dx) \\
& \leq \frac{1}{u^2}\int_{[-\frac{1}{u},\frac{1}{u}]} \left(2 - 2 \cos(ux) + \frac{1}{12} (ux)^4 \right)\mathbb{P}_X(dx),
\end{align}
and of course it is clear that
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{Re} \: \phi(u) = \int \cos (ux) \mathbb{P}_{X}(dx).
\end{equation}
But I'm having trouble continuing from here. I suppose it's mostly the $x^4$ in the integrandum that is bugging me, as I have no idea how to bound this in a way that makes it clear that the inequality holds. Any help would be much appreciated.
Edit - I think I have found it! By the above we have
\begin{align}
1 - \mathrm{Re} \: \phi(u) & = 1 - \int_{\mathbb{R}} \cos(ux) \mathbb{P}_X(dx) \\ 
& = \int_{\mathbb{R}} (1 - \cos(ux)) \mathbb{P}_X(dx),
\end{align}
where the last equality follows since $\mathbb{P}$ is a probability measure. Then
\begin{equation}
\int_{\mathbb{R}} (1 - \cos(ux)) \mathbb{P}_X(dx) \geq \int_{[-\frac{1}{u}, \frac{1}{u}]} (1 - \cos(ux) )\mathbb{P}_X(dx),
\end{equation}
by the fact that $1 - \cos(ux) \geq 0$. Then using the second hint we find
\begin{equation}
\int_{[-\frac{1}{u}, \frac{1}{u}]} (1 - \cos(ux) )\mathbb{P}_X(dx) \geq \int_{[-\frac{1}{u}, \frac{1}{u}]} \left(\frac{1}{2} (ux)^2 - \frac{1}{24} (ux)^4 \right)\mathbb{P}_X(dx).
\end{equation}
This in its turn implies that
\begin{align}
\frac{24}{u^2} \left( 1 - \mathrm{Re} \: \phi(u) \right) & \geq \int_{[-\frac{1}{u},\frac{1}{u}]} (12 x^2 - u^2 x^4) \mathbb{P}_X(dx).
\end{align}
However, clearly
\begin{equation}
x^4 \leq \frac{x^2}{u^2}, \qquad x \in [-\frac{1}{u},\frac{1}{u}].
\end{equation}
Thus, our last inequality becomes
\begin{align}
\int_{[-\frac{1}{u},\frac{1}{u}]} (12 x^2 - u^2 x^4) \mathbb{P}_X(dx) & \geq \int_{[-\frac{1}{u},\frac{1}{u}]} (12 x^2 -  u^2 \frac{x^2}{u^2}) \mathbb{P}_X(dx) \\
& = \int_{[-\frac{1}{u},\frac{1}{u}]} 11 x^2 \mathbb{P}_X(dx)
\end{align}
Combining this with the start,
we find that
\begin{equation}
\frac{24}{11u^2} (1 - \mathrm{Re} \: \phi(u) ) \geq \int_{[-\frac{1}{u},\frac{1}{u}]} x^2 \mathbb{P}_X(dx),
\end{equation}
as desired.
Once I got out of my head and noticed the inequality $x^4 \leq x^2/u^2$ for $|x| \leq 1/u$, everything was already there.

That seems correct :)
